# Lectura de archivos con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quiero que mi código use los datos que me provee un archivo que esta en la misma raíz, se que se hace con el constructor FileReader() pero estoy aprendiendo a programar y no entiendo como debería funcionar.

Ejemplo: sumar dos números que provee el archivo numeros.txt

El archivo numeros contiene lo siguiente:

```
3 7
```

El codigo para solucionar esto seria:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a+b;
}
```

Disculpen lo novato.

Comment: Por protocolor tengo que recomentarte que tomes el [tour] y visites la sección [ask] porque tu pregunta es muy difusa y la idea es que acá nos muestres **qué has intentado** y qué es **en concreto** lo que te impide seguir, pero como veo que necesitas ayuda para algo no tan trivial y no me gusta mandar a la gente por un desvío que te resultará muy largo, preferí dar una respuesta específica a tu problema porque se puede inferir lo que necesitas hacer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considerando que la pregunta puede ser en el browser como en **node.js**, las respuestas serían:

---

## En el browser

El browser no tiene acceso a tus archivo locales a menos que tú explícitamente uses un input de tipo `file` y elijas un archivo. (De lo contrario el browser podría leer todo tu disco local y eso sería un hoyo de seguridad gigante)

```
 <input type="file" id="archivo">
```

Dato ese input en el DOM, añades un listener a tu elemento de tipo `input type=file`.

```
document.getElementById("archivo").addEventListener("change", (event) => {

});
```

Dentro de esa función, instancias un FileReader

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
```

A ese fileReader le pones un listener que se ejecute cuando el archivo haya cargado. El contenido del archivo estará en la propiedad `result`

```
fileReader.onload = function (e) {
    var contents = fileReader.result;
};
```

luego pasas el archivo que se seleccionó en el input y le dices que lo lea como texto:

```
fileReader.readAsText(files[0]);
```

Nótese que `files` pueden ser varios archivos si el input es múltiple, por lo que, aunque acepte un solo archivo, `files` es un array y en este caso queremos el único archivo, `files[0]`.

Al terminar de leerlo invocará la función de arriba.

Si tienes certeza de que el archivo es un texto que tiene números separados por espacios, te dejo un ejemplo práctico que permitiría (si quisieras) sumar más de dos números, cambiando el footprint de la función (pero es un detalle que en este caso es irrelevante)

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
document.getElementById("archivo").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  var files = document.getElementById("archivo").files;
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = fileReader.result,
      argumentos = contents.split(/\s+/);
    argumentos_numericos = argumentos.map((argumento) => {
      return 1 * argumento
    });
    console.log(sum.apply(sum, argumentos_numericos));



  };
  fileReader.readAsText(files[0]);

}, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="archivo">
```

Nota: no estoy haciendo ninguna validación y la conversión de los argumentos de texto a número para hacer la suma la estoy haciendo burdamente, multiplicando el string por 1.

---

## En node.js

Usas el módulo `fs` incorporado en node.

```
fs = require('fs');
```

En node tienes acceso a todos los archivos del disco por lo que puedes hacer:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('numeros.txt');
//    ... hacer algo con data...
```

O bien

```
fs.readFile('numeros.txt', (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
       console.error(err);
       return;
    }
    ... hacer algo con data ...
});
```

La diferencia entre usar `readFileSync` vs `readFile` es que el primero bloquea el event-loop mientras que el segundo te permitiría seguir haciendo otras cosas mientras se lee el archivo. En este ejemplo, es irrelevante.

Pero acá es importante notar que al usar cualquiera de estos dos métodos, **lo que recibes en `data` es un [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)**. Y ese Buffer debes convertirlo a `string` para usarlo como quieres.

```
try {
   let data = fs.readFileSync('numeros.txt'),
   contenido = data.toString('UTF8');
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
```

¿Por qué envuelvo todo en un bloque `try/catch`? Bueno, es equivalente a la manera como detectas el error en la versión asíncrona. Si el archivo no existe obtiene un error de tipo `ENOENT` o si no tiene permisos de lectura un error de tipo `EACCES`.

Ahora `contenido` contiene (valga la rebuznancia) el string `1 2`.

Ese contenido lo conviertes en un array de enteros usando

```
enterosArray = contenido.split(" ").map(num=> parseInt(num, 10))
```

Si te fijas, `parseInt` espera dos argumentos. El string que debes castear a `integer` y el radix-parameter. Por defecto se asume que quieres convertir a entero con base 10, pero si tu archivo contuviese:

```
01 11
```

- `parseInt(num,10)` sería 1 y 11
- `parseInt(num,2)` sería 1 y 3
- `parseInt(num,16)` sería 1 y 17.

Si omites el radix-parameter, un linter te alegaría por el uso de `parseInt(num)` diciendo:

```
missing-radix-parameter
```

Luego tienes la función que hace la suma. En tu pregunta la función era:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a+b;
}
```

Que espera dos sumandos y devuelve su suma. Si quieres que acepte un array y devuelva su suma, puedes hacer como planteas en tu respuesta:

```
function sum(data) {
  data.map((num) => solved+=num)
  console.log(solved);
}
```

Con dos salvedades:

1. `solved` no está definido, tendrías que inicializarlo poniendo antes

   let solved = 0;
2. Una función arrow no debiera retornar una asignación (un linter te dirá `no-return-assign`  así que dentro del `map` debieras usar

   let solved = 0;
    data.map((num) => { 
       let resultado_parcial = solved += num;
    });
    console.log(solved);

Pero estás declarando `resultado_parcial` sin mayor relevancia. Sería más elegante omitir la declaración de `solved` y usar `Array.reduce`

```
let solved = data.reduce((accum, num) => {
    accum += num;
    return accum;
}, 0);

console.log(solved);
```

Otra solución posible sería usar el `spread operator` definiendo la función como:

```
function sum(...data) {
    let solved = data.reduce((accum, num) => { 
        accum += num;
        return accum;
    }, 0);

    console.log(solved);
}
```

Con lo cual serías libre de llamarla ya sea como

```
let resultado = sum(1,2,3,4,5);
```

o como

```
let resultado = sum.apply(sum, [1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Pero esto último es sólo un detalle que queda a tu criterio.

---

## Validación del input:

Supongamos que no conoces el contenido de `numeros.txt`, pero sabes que de él debes obtener un array de números. Si el contenido fuese

```
 '1 2 3 4'
```

No habría problema en usar `.split(' ')`

¿Pero qué pasaría si el contenido fuese:    `1|2,3 aaa 4_5-6.7`?

En ese caso podrías pedir que separe el string aceptando como separador cualquier cosas que no sea un número pasándole una expresión regular a `split`:

```js
   var enterosArray = '1|2,3 aaa 4_5-6.7'.split(/[^\d]+/).map(num => parseInt(num,10))
   console.log(enterosArray);
```

Comment: Oye gracias por reponder, pero mi problema radica en que estoy en un grupo de gitlab y piden que mi codigo a integrar use cierto criterios, por ejemplo usar los datos de un archivo que esta en el repositorio. Si uso la terminología correcta? es que soy nuevo en js, pido disculpas. posdata: es bueno probar código javascript en la consola del navegador? o que alternativas sugieres. Saludos

Comment: No tiene nada de malo probar en la consola del navegador, pero ésta no es un equivalente a un `node REPL` por lo cual no podrías hacerlo mismo que en node

Answer (score 0):

al respuesta anterior es perfecta para frontend, en backend seria algo así:

```
const fileReader = require('fs');


function sum(data) {
  data.map((num) => solved+=num)
  console.log(solved);
}

function fileLoad() {
  return fileReader.readFile('numeros.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
      err ? err : sum(data.split(" ").map((num) => parseInt(num) ));
  });
} 

fileLoad();
```

esto corre en node.js, lo que se esta haciendo es importar el modulo fs con la palabra reservada require().

```
const fileReader = require('fs');
```

Luego de esto podemos leer el archivo con la variable fileReader, pues es la que contiene todo el modulo. el modulo fs(File System, esta es su documentación https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html) tiene una función llamada readFile que recibe varios parámetros, el primero es la ruta del archivo, , el tercero es un callback que tiene dos parámetros "err" y "data", en caso de que exista un error, retorna el tipo de error (posdata, "?" es igual al "if" pero en este caso esta en una sola linea) en caso contrario envía los datos a una función llamada "sum".

```
sum(data.split(" ").map((num) => parseInt(num)
```

Esta parte del código podría se un poco confusa para los que apenas estamos aprendiendo a programar, aquí le estoy enviando los parámetros a "sum", pero en forma de un array y su vez los convierto en enteros. si no entienden lo que sucede busquen los métodos split() y map().

```
function sum(data) {
 data.map((num) => solved+=num)
 console.log(solved);
}
```

Aquí sucede la magia de la suma, y listo.
Saludos

Comment: Eso está casi bien, pero al usar `fs.readFile` lo que obtienes es un buffer. Por lo tanto debieras hacer `fileReader(..., (err, data) => {   sum(data.toString('UTF8").split(...)  })` si no usas toString sobre el buffer, éste no tiene un método `split`

Comment: Creo que en el momento de decirle .split(" "), me genera un array de strings, asi que da lo mismo.
saludos.